# Как заставить персонажа двигаться вниз?

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

Я хочу реализовать движение объекта вниз на кнопку `S`, но получаю ошибку:

```
using UnityEngine;
 
public class MOVINGPLAYERFINALLY : MonoBehaviour {
public int speed = 5;
public GameObject player;
 
   void Start()
   {
    player = (GameObject)this.gameObject; 
   }
  
   void Update()
   {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
       {
       player.transform.position += player.transform.up * speed * Time.deltaTime;
       }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
       {
        player.transform.position -= player.transform.down * speed * Time.deltaTime;
       }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
       {
        player.transform.position += player.transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
       }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
       {
        player.transform.position -= player.transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
       }                                             
   }
}
```

Компилятор жалуется на строку `player.transform.position -= player.transform.down * speed * Time.deltaTime;`, а именно на момент `down *`
Как решить проблему?

Comment: А что изобрели такую переменную как transform.down?

Comment: На будущее: в вопросе НЕ нужно приветствие,  в вопросе НЕ нужно упоминание движка, так как unity вы указываете меткой [unity3d]

Answer (score 2):

Существует только [transform.up](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-up.html) И [transform.right](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-right.html)

Переменных transform.down и transform.left **НЕ** существует, однако, так как верх противоположен низу, и лево — праву, вы можете использовать

```
-transform.up
-transform.right
```

Соответственно пишем:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
      {
       player.transform.position -= player.transform.up * speed * Time.deltaTime;
      }
```

НЕ добавляем минус перед transform.up, так как он уже стоит в `-=`

Answer (score 2):

```
Vector3 Vector = Vector3.zero;
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    Vector += Vector3.up;
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    Vector += Vector3.down;
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    Vector += Vector3.right;
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    Vector += Vector3.left;
player.transform.position += Vector*speed*Time.deltaTime;
```

Ещё проще:

```
Vector3 Vector = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0);
player.transform.position += Vector*speed*Time.deltaTime;
```

А вообще ответ содержится в тексте ошибки!